# "Unable to Connect to the Remote Server" when connected via .NET ReportingService web service call

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have reporting services running on SQL Server 2008 inside the domain. I'm able to hit http://localhost/reportserver without error.  I can hit the same site from the web box (also in the domain name) using the internal ip of the DB box (192.169.X.X/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx.)  I've looked in the SSRS logs and I see these hits being properly recorded, no errors.

However.. I have a website that uses the .NET ReportingService class to make a connection to SSRS.  Using the same credentials as before, I get "Unable to connect to the remote server."

I've checked, there's no firewall active.  Quadrupled checked the config in the web site to make sure it has the proper credentials and service URL for SSRS. There are also no hits in the SSRS logs when I'm trying to connect via .NET, so something is most certainly blocking access.

I've Googled my fingers bloody, and would seriously love some help. I'm sure it's some small thing, I just can't think of it.

Comment: [dba.SE answer that solved this for me](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82413/68127). Issue for me was [removing SSL settings after config'ing a local instance](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/686214/removing-ssl-cert-in-config-manager-doesnt-properly-modify-rsreportserver-config). TL,DR; in your `rsreportserver.config` set `Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="0"`

Answer (score 1):

The following change worked for me:

1. Remove the SSL configuration

   1.1. Reporting Services Configuration Manager;

   1.2. Web Service URL (click on Advanced button and then remove the SSL configuration);

   1.3. Report Manager URL (click on Advanced button and then remove the SSL configuration);
2. Edit the file rsreportserver.config, normally it's in the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\

   2.1. find out the Key SecureConnectionLevel;

   2.2. change the Key's value from "2" to "0";

Answer (score 0):

Could be your reporting services is exposed only to the private ip and your localhost. Try setting your domain name's static ip to the configuration. I've added a [SSRS Url configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx) link for your quick reference.

Comment: Reporting guy checked the configuration, said that it's already added.    I tried switching the website to use the external IP for ReportService, and still no dice.

Comment: Some more items to check. When you ping for your server name, does it return the static ip? are you able to load the url via browser? I mean with your http://externalip/reportserver. If this does not work you might have it blocked with the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:
1. Remove the SSL if configured.
2. Go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
3. In rsreportserver.config Change the SecureConnectionLevel value from "2" to "0"

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me: I Removed the SSL and set it to 0 vs 2 in the path 
G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer   file is reportserver.config file.

Basically it was previously configured with SSL at port 443 but the server has been moved to another domain, and did not know where to go to get a new SSL certificate for this domain,
So i removed the SSL config in the reporting services configuration GUI and then remove it also in the reportserver.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your report URL ends with /Reportserver/ (For the purpose of .NET code calling). Also keep in mind that you should use complete URL i.e. It should include servername and domain.

[Check this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fcf619e-1599-4a12-a996-a847082da8ea/whats-my-report-server-url?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

I like the other solutions however in my instance I had to update the following. For some reason or another the service wasn't able to use 127.0.0.1, localhost, or any of the other IP addresses assigned to the computer, this method however worked.

1. Open "Report Server Configuration Manager"
2. Web Service URL

   1. Click on Advanced Button
   2. Click the IP entry that I wanted to edit.
   3. Click "Host Header Name" and type in the fully qualified name for the server.
3. Report Manager URL

   1. Click on Advanced Button
   2. Click the IP entry that I wanted to edit.
   3. Click "Host Header Name" and type in the fully qualified name for the server.

After the above were done both URLs in "Web Service URL" and "Report Manager URL" were able to work once correct credentials were passed to the server.